# Partial Sum of the Binomial Theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients

The binomial theorem states $\sum_{k=0}^nC_n^kr^k=(1+r)^n$. I am interested in the function \begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^mC_n^kr^k, \quad m<n
\end{equation} 
for fixed $n$ and $r$, and both $m$ and $n$ are integers. Are there any notable properties for this function? Any literature references?

In particular, do any good closed-form approximations exist for this partial sum of the binomial theorem?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93744/estimating-a-partial-sum-of-weighted-binomial-coefficients?rq=1 http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55585/lower-bound-for-sum-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: For fixed n and r, this is a "function" of what variable?

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for tail estimates for the binomial distribution. An introduction can be found [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_Bounds) - this has pointers to further work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one interesting property:

MR2147385
Ostrovskii, Iossif V.
On a problem of A. Eremenko. 
Comput. Methods Funct. Theory 4 (2004), no. 2, 275–282.